# Twitter Kit cannot be redirect in Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, redirect, twitter

TwitterKit cannot be Redirect in my app.
[image: In TwitterKit cannot be Redirect in my app and also i am added all important code]

**1. Info.Plist**
Added lines

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>twitterkit-{your consumer key}</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>twitterauth</string>
</array>
```

**2. App delegate**

```
import TwitterKit
application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:consumer_key, consumerSecret:consumer_secret)
}

application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

**3. LoginScreen**

```
func twitter(){
    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(with: self, completion: { (session, error) in
          --
    }) 
}
```

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please format the code correctly, someone can down vote your question

Answer (score 0):

this is a callBack problem 
So 
Please Comment AppDelegate in the

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set) {
}
and Add didFinishlaunchWithOption function in

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let vc =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GoThrough") as! UINavigationController
self.window?.rootViewController = vc
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()